# chrome https proxy not working, but http does

Tags: google-chrome, https, http-proxy

I run an http server on port 9999, an https server on port 8000;

Then I set the http proxy to localhost:9999, so all http requests will got the response from my http server.

But when I set the https proxy to localhost:8000, and request some https address, chrome got a blank page: This page isn't working. xxx didn't send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. Why is this happen?

[proxy config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFmY7.jpg)

[proxy config2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPY95.jpg)